# How to capture output of a command run in python3 in python2?

Tags: python, list, subprocess

I have a file which connects a database and fetches the result. Now the file must be ran using `python 3` and my project uses `python 2.7`. So I run the file as a command line using `subprocess` module. Here is how I call the file.

```
import subprocess
import ast

def execute_python3(param):
    param = param.replace("\\", "")
    param = "\"" + param + "\""

    cmd = "python3 " + "get_db_result.py" + " " + param

    result = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
    return ast.literal_eval(result)

execute_python3(sql_query)
```

Here in the command, I am passing sql query to the `get_db_result` file.

The `get_db_result.py` file looks something like this

```
import sys
def get_result():
    param = sys.argv[1]
    '''
    Logic to get result from db
    '''
    result = db_output
    print(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_result()
```

Now the issue is when I fetch the output from db, I have to do a `print` for the output to be captured by the `subprocess` module. This makes it difficult to parse the output to be used by program for further work. For example, when I receive an output like this

```
"[(u'Delhi', 20199330), (u'Mumbai', 134869470), (u'Kolkata', 6678446)]"
```

This is a string list of tuples which can be converted to list of tuples by doing something like `ast.literal_eval(result)`

But sometimes I get output like this

```
"[(datetime.date(2019, 5, 27), 228.168093587), (datetime.date(2019, 5, 28), 228.834493641)]"
```

Here `ast` doesn't understand `datetime`. Even `json.loads()` doesn't work on this.

How can I capture the output from a file without having to use `print` and simply return it back to `subprocess` as it is. Is it even possible?

Comment: Since you have `datetime` in the string, you'll probably need to resort to `eval`

Comment: Why not serialize the data (e.g., to JSON) and deserializing on the other end?

Comment: Your title is very misleading. Your problem has nothing to do with capturing the output, your problem is with converting the output to a useful value.

Comment: BTW, rather tha constructing the command as a string, you should use a list. Then you don't have to play games with escape characters and quotes.

Comment: If you have the script, I would extract the parts that actually do the query into a library, rather than trying to parse the output created from the query result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to serialize and deserialize the data on both ends. Simplest solution would be to use Python's `pickle` module and hope the types that are serialized on the Python 3 end, are similar enough to those on the deserializing Python 2 end.  You need to specify the used protocol on the sending end to a version understood by the receiving end:

Receiver with safer call of subprocess (no shell process in between):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pickle
import subprocess


def execute_python3(param):
    result = subprocess.check_output(['python3', 'get_db_result.py', param])
    return pickle.loads(result)


def main():
    execute_python3(sql_query)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Sender, explicitly choosing a pickle protocol still understood by Python 2:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import pickle


def get_result():
    param = sys.argv[1]
    '''
    Logic to get result from db
    '''
    result = db_output
    pickle.dump(result, sys.stdout.buffer, protocol=2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_result()
```

If this doesn't work because of differences in the (de)serialized objects between Python 2 and 3, you have to fall back to explicitly (de)serialize the data, for example in JSON, as suggested by a comment from Jay.

Comment: Fantastico fratello mio! This works for me. Using pickle is actually smart since I do not have to deal with data until it is received in python 2.